# ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports

Tags: javascript, typescript

### Question:

Why am I getting the following error? Did I forget to include a script in my html?

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: exports

### Generated javascript from typescript that causes it:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
/* more code */
```

### Extra:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceRoot": "../../../",
    "outDir": "../../../js/dist/",
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

*requirejs is included before my js files in html*

*There are similar questions but this is simply about typescript and not about ember/babel/etc.*

Comment: Maybe one of these will help you https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues/845 or https://github.com/wallabyjs/public/issues/160

Comment: @lonut thanks for the links, however they were not what I was looking for.

Comment: Can you show us your Gruntfile? Are you using System.js (is there a reference to system.js and/or system.js.config somewhere in your project)? I've encountered the same problem and have managed to fix it.

Comment: @ACOMIT001 if no module is specified then I believe by default commonjs is chosen. I'm using the tsc compiler and not grunt. I've also tried by specifying the system module, but was unable to get it to work properly.  What was your solution?

Comment: I was actually having a similar problem with Jasmine. Creating a file with exports defined managed to fix the issue.

Comment: Is this project for the browser? If so try following this tutorial: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/quick/browser.html

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce. Your `tsconfig.json` causes `tsc` to bail with

> error TS5051: Option 'sourceRoot can only be used when either option '--inlineSourceMap' or option '--sourceMap' is provided.

Once I remove the `sourceRoot` option, there are no references to `exports` in the output.

---

$ ls

```
my.ts       tsconfig.json
```

$ cat my.ts

```
console.log(1)
```

$ cat tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "rootDir": ".",
    "sourceRoot": "../../../",
    "outDir": "../../../js/dist/",
    "sourceMap": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

$ tsc --version

```
Version 3.5.3
```